# preg_split with closing tag

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this

```
$string = '[c]str1[/c][c]str2[/c][c]str3[/c][c]str4[/c][c]str5[/c]';
```

I want to split it to get all strX in an array

So far I managed to do like this

```
$strarray = preg_split('/\[.](.*?)\[\/.]/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

But the result I get is

```
array (
  0 => '',
  1 => 'str1',
  2 => '',
  3 => 'str2',
  4 => '',
  5 => 'str3',
  6 => '',
  7 => 'str4',
  8 => '',
  9 => 'str5',
  10 => '',
)
```

Is there any regex pattern to get rid of the blank array elements directly (I don't want to loop through $strarray to remove blank elements unless it is the only solution)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `preg_split` with [`PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) flag:

> **`PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`**
>   *If this flag is set, only non-empty pieces will be returned by `preg_split()`.*

Code:

```
$strarray = preg_split('/\[.](.*?)\[\/.]/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/4WPBw4)

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => str1
    [1] => str2
    [2] => str3
    [3] => str4
    [4] => str5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_match_all

```
preg_match_all('~\[.]\K.*?(?=\[\/.])~', $str, $matches);
```

or

```
preg_match_all('~\[(.)]\K.*?(?=\[\/\1])~', $str, $matches);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dO0mM8/5)